# Session in different applications Symfony2

Tags: symfony, session, fosuserbundle

I have three Symfony2 applications running on different servers, I can not keep me logged in on more than one application at the same time.

When I do I log into one of the applications automatically when I try to access another application in which I was already logged in I am required to login again.

I believe they are sharing a session ID or something.

Could someone enlighten me what happens and how to solve this problem?

Thank you

Comment: Check the security.yml to make sure you use `context: shared_value` in each apps firewall

Comment: Hi, I will try here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html thanks