# symfony2 how to store session differently on one domain/IP with to different application

Tags: php, session, fosuserbundle, symfony-2.3

I have two different projects in symfony2. I am using symfony2.3 version.

I have used fosuserbundle for user authentication.

I have one server. I have uploaded my both projects at

1. /var/www/html/project1
2. /var/www/html/project2

And i am accessing my two applications/projects like

1. http://202.12.0.0/project1 and
2. http://202.12.0.0//project2.

(IP here is given only for example. It's not my IP which i am using).

My problem is when I login in http://202.12.0.0/project1 it store session for taking http://202.12.0.0 as domain.

So when I login in http://202.12.0.0/project2, It logout from http://202.12.0.0/project1. I need to login again.

And V/S same for project2.

I have no other option for that. I mean i have no option for virtual host for this two different project. I have LAN, and every one using this project/my-application using IPaddress/project.

I Referred [Session in different applications Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24891328/session-in-different-applications-symfony2) But it doesn't help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably should configure both projects to use different place where session files are stored.

In Symfony2 you can do that with `save_path` param in framework configuration

More info: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/session/sessions_directory.html

Also it can be done strictly in PHP with [session_save_path](http://php.net/session_save_path) function.

Edit.
Also changing just session name could work too. You can do that either by framework configuration or by [session_name](http://php.net/session_name) PHP function.

Comment: Thanks for solution. I had tries earlier using save_path. But it couldn't helped me. But I get success using session_name.